# How to compile ffmpeg for Qt use on Windows?

Tags: windows, qt, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg libs for programming in Qt.

- How can I compile ffmpeg into *.lib files on Windows?

or

- How can I use the compiled *.dll files which are released officially in Qt?

Also, which way is better?